# active or passive

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice

> 1.Works of art displayed inside the museum are ranged from 6 to the 13 century.
>
> 2.Works of art displayed inside the museum ranges from 6 to the 13 century.

As I found the word "range" can use both transitive and intransistive verb, which is suitable for this sentence,
active voice or passive voice?

Comment: I'd say: 

Works of art displayed inside the museum range from the 6th to the 13 century.  I am uncertain about grammar and you might need the word to be *centuries*.

Comment: You need to say _Works of art displayed inside the museum range from the 6th to the 13 century_, where "range" would be present tense active voice

Comment: The passive voice doesn't really make sense here, because it implies an action performed by somebody else.  Is somebody else "ranging" the works?

Answer (score 1):

You've already written both sentences in the active voice.  "Are ranged" is not passive, it's an adjectival phrase that modifies "works of art".

So a better question is how to best phrase this.  As in BillJ's comment:

> Works of art displayed inside the museum **range** from the 6th to the 13 century

Passive voice would be if the works of art were acted on by someone or something:

> The works of art **were arranged** by the date they were created.

This would be the passive of "someone *arranged* the works of art ..."